# Alarm Script in bash shell

Tags: bash, unix

I wanted to write a small script which displays a image or play a song at the particular time. What is the best way(which consumes less RAM) to do that ?

One way I thought is to Recursively query for time using `date` command and run it through a for loop(checks for hours) within a for loop(checks for minutes) until time reaches the preset time.

Is it the correct approach? are there any other Smart ways of writing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think the best way would be to create a cron job.

With cron you don't have to worry about timing etc, you just create a task. Take a look at its [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and manual, it's really simple.

You can find an example how to set things up [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=213&t=77603&p=459886). It's based on Mint Linux, but should work on any distribution.

Answer (score 2):

In your `crontab` :

```
0 7 * * * DISPLAY=:0 display /path/to/image.png; mplayer /path/to/sound.ogg
```

That will display `image.png` and play `sound.ogg` each days at 07 AM.

Adapt it to your needs.

- `display` comes with `imagemagick`
- `mplayer` comes with `mplayer`

Answer (score 0):

cron is great for running tasks at the same time(s) every day/week/month. If you just want to run a task once at some future time, use [`at`](http://man.cx/at). One great thing about `at` is that it runs in a copy of your current environment, unlike cron.